# Display RadEditor content in asp:literal

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I have used RadEditor for displaying rich-text, it works perfectly.

Now in the next form i want to show its output using `asp:literal`.

This `asp:literal` is not displaying bullets,italic and bold characters that were been displayed in RadEditor.

The problem in my opinion: CSS class which i have used throughout application, `asp:literal` is using that.

How can I disable this default CSS and using a class which display every data which was in RadEditor?

here is RadEditor input:

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID = "RadSpecification" runat = "server" Height="200px" 
                    ToolbarMode="ShowOnFocus" MaxTextLength = "4000"
                    AutoResizeHeight="True" ContentAreaMode="Iframe" 
                    EmptyMessage="Product Specification" Skin="Telerik" StripFormattingOptions="None" 
                    ToolTip="Product Specification" RenderMode="Classic" 
                    StripFormattingOnPaste="None" EditModes="Design" Width="500px" 
                    NewLineMode="Div" OnClientLoad ="RadEditorLoad">
    <CssFiles>
        <telerik:EditorCssFile Value="~/EditorContentArea.css" />
    </CssFiles>
    <Tools>
    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "Bold" />
        <telerik:EditorTool name ="Italic" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "Underline" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "InsertUnorderedList" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "InsertOrderedList" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "JustifyLeft" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "JustifyRight" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "JustifyCenter" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "JustifyFull" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "Undo" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "Redo" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "ConvertToUpper" />
        <telerik:EditorTool Name = "ConvertToLower" />
    </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
    </Tools>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

Comment: Can you show me HTML code of your Content ?

Comment: plz reply with answer as soon as possible

Comment: Does the literal display the rest of styles (fonts colors, bacgrounds etc.) ?

Comment: No , Khan . I means your content which display in your Editor and Literal !